# How to give restrictions for spesific time?

Tags: php

How to give restriction any user admin or any role for a spesific time e. g 30 days in Php and automatically given role or restriction will cancle after 30 days.

Comment: Can you share your code?

Answer (score 0):

When you update the member's to admin, add the date to the db. On checking the role, you just have to take a look to the date and if it's over, you ignored it.